# How to disable the effect of caps lock while in normal mode in vim?

Tags: vim

When the CAPS lock is ON in normal mode, the vim behaves in an abnormal way.
Is there a way to disable this effect of CAPS lock when editing in normal mode?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the Caps Lock state is managed by your operating system, integrating from within Vim with it, while possible, is difficult and prone to break. Instead, I would recommend to implement a "soft" Caps Lock within Vim (for those RARE_CASES where this is needed), and avoid the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key when using Vim. (Some argue that it's best remapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>; I agree.)

The [Insert-mode only Caps Lock](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert-mode_only_Caps_Lock) page on the Vim Tips Wiki lists multiple approaches for such a soft Caps Lock. (There are also pages for remapping the key.)

Answer (score -9):

Vim *doesn't* behave in abnormal ways when caps lock is on.

Rather, most lowercase commands have uppercase counterparts that behave differently. If you have caps lock on, you will probably execute commands you didn't intend to.

Comment: That's perfectly normal and expected: uppercase letters all have a different (but related) meaning in normal mode than their lowercase counterparts: "a" means "enter insert mode to the right of the cursor" but "A" means "enter insert mode at the end of the line". Same for "iI", "bB", "7&" and so on. If you want "a" press "a", not "A".

Comment: Yes, it is documented all over Vim's documentation. When you do `:help a`, the uppercase version is usually not far away but you can do `:help A` if you are in a hurry. See `:help index` for the complete list of commands and `:help normal-index` for the complete list of normal mode commands.